# UICollectionViewCell dynamic height depending on UITextView font lineHeight

Tags: ios, uicollectionview

I am trying to implement a collection view with cells having a dynamic height.

Some of the collection view cells contains UITextView, the UITextViews have their height configured like this :

```
    [textViewHeightConstraint setConstant: numberOfRowsToDisplay * [[textView font] lineHeight]];
```

The textview is a subview of a another view which is in a specific .xib, this xib view is added as subview of the cell when the cell is dequeued (when collectionView:cellForItemAtIndexPath: is called).

BUT i need to return the height of the cell in the "collectionView:sizeForItemAtIndexPath:" method where the cell instance is not accessible, so i cannot access the textview : [[textView font] lineHeight] property.

How can i solve that ?

PS : the textview are empty, so the height is not dependent of an NSString on which i can call the sizeWithFont: method, and i cannot hard code the textview height. The "numberOfRowsToDisplay" is retrieved at runtime, and the textView font is not hardcoded too.

EDIT : i already tried to call "dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:forIndexPath:" in the "collectionView:sizeForItemAtIndexPath:" method, it creates an infinite loop, as if i was calling "collectionView:cellForItemAtIndexPath:".

Comment: You should not be trying to access the cell. You should be querying the data source for the numberOfRowsToDisplay value for the particular indexPath. Cells are for displaying data only, not for supplying it.

Comment: Yep, you can't arbitrarily dequeue cells for calculating heights like you can with `UITableView`. Very annoying.

Comment: @rdelmar it is not the "numberOfRowsToDisplay" which is hard to retrieve, it's the lineHeight of the textView, the textView is in the cell, so i can't access its font property.

Comment: Do the text views in different rows have different fonts?

Comment: You say that both font and numberOfRowsToDisplay are gotten at runtime, so both should be part of your data, which you have access to. If you need to, you can just have a single UITextView (not in your cell), and use it to calculate the height based on your two variables.

Comment: The textview will be in a xib in a final app, but i'm working on a static library, the xib will be in a final app that will use the library. So at the moment, i can't know which font will be used in the xib containing the textview. Anyway, i think i solved my problem, the only way i found is to instantiate the xib (and the textview contained in it) just to retrieve the font and the lineheight.

Answer (score -1):

You need to set your view controller as a delegate for the flow layout class.

See here: [UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout Protocol Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout_protocol/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: The view controller is already a delegate of the layout class, the problem is that i need a cell instance to know the height of the cell, and the system needs the height to create a cell... = vicious circle